# vim copy/paste from system clipboard

Tags: vim

hi I have macOS High Sierra, and vim with the version `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jul 26 2017 19:10:24)`

I used to be able to copy a text like `:%s/abc//g` into system clipboard, and go to a terminal where vim is current editing a file, and paste by doing `cmd+v`, and then it will just run in normal mode to do the full-text replacement.

However, I find now that this process will just paste the text `:%s/abc//g` in the file currently being edited, seemingly in the insert mode.

How can I get back the behavior of normal mode? Tried `:set nopaste` without any luck.

Comment: `:let @+=@:`  ? If you want to copy the last command typed to clipboard ? But the quesiton is not clear, if you want to add each match to the clipboard (+ register), use the \= replacement to evaluate the match and add it to @+

Answer (score 4):

#### Method 1

1. Enter command mode by typing `:`.
2. Now execute `<C-r>+` to paste from clipboard.
3. Hit enter.

#### Method 2

1. In normal mode, type `q:` to enter command history mode.
2. Paste using `"+p`.
3. Hit enter.

---

You might even consider creating a mapping.

```
" Paste to command mode while in insert mode.
inoremap <C-v> <C-o>:<C-r>+

" Not recommended. You can't go into Visual Block mode anymore.
nnoremap <C-v> <C-o>:<C-r>+
```

Comment: You may not get what I was asking: I wanted to restore to the previous state  where I don't need to type anything and it automatically is already in normal mode. I was asking if there is a switch for that.

Comment: Is the remapping closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Using method one only causes Vim to freeze for me. I can't change modes or exit without terminating my SSH session.

Comment: Method 2 works when using [Vim emulation extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Plug [vim-system-copy](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-system-copy). I found it very helpful for me.